# How to define the query filter for the following situation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have defined my model as following , and how to define a query to filter the Sanity_Test set which the associated Test_Product's product name are in the specified name list ? Many thanks

For example:

1. Sanity_Test_A contains Test_Product_A(Product name was A) , Test_Product_B(Product name was B)
2. Sanity_Test_B contains Test_Product_C(Product name was A) , Test_Product_D(Product name was C)
3. I want to filter the Sanity_Test record list which it's Test_Product record's Product name is A

## APP : CT.model

```
class Sanity_Test(models.Model):

    build        = models.OneToOneField('CI.Build')                                                           
    system_test  = models.ForeignKey(System_Test,null=True,blank=True)

    ......


class Test_Product(models.Model):

    product     = models.ForeignKey('CI.Product',verbose_name='Product')            
    sanity_test = models.ForeignKey(Sanity_Test)

    ......


# APP : CI.model 
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

    ......
```

[The Test_Product Record Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZSzZ.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
sanity_test = [ test_product.sanity_set for test_productin Test_Product.objects.filter(product__name='A')]
```

This gets all Test_Product objects with product name A, and then adds the corresponding sanity_test object to the list

Comment: That's what I expected ,  thank you so much for your kindly help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with only one query using [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
sanity_test = Sanity_Test.objects.filter(test_product__product__name='A')
```

Comment: Yes, because `test_product` has a foreign key to `sanity_test`. It's called `reverse relationship`. From the docs: "It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model."